# Is it possible to reconstruct the compact space $X$ from the space of measures $M(X)$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff topological space and $C(X)$ the Banach algebra of continuous functions $u:X\to\mathbb C$ (with the usual $\sup$-norm). It is well-known that the structure of Banach algebra with involution (or, we can say, the structure of a C*-algebra) on $C(X)$ allows to restore the topological space $X$:

- the points of $X$ can be restored as (continuous) involutive charaters $\chi:C(X)\to \mathbb C$, and
- the topology on $X$ is induced on these characters as the $C(X)$-weak topology on the space $C(X)^*$ of continuous functionals on $C(X)$.

If we consider the dual space $M(X)=C(X)^*$ of Radon measures (i.e. linear continuous functionals $\mu:C(X)\to \mathbb C$), then the possibility to restore $X$ from $M(X)$ seems to depend on the topology on $M(X)=C(X)^*$ that we choose:

- Everything is simple if we endow $M(X)=C(X)^*$ with the compact-open topology (i.e. the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets in $C(X)$), then $M(X)=C(X)^*$ turns into a [stereotype involutive coalgebra](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10958-017-3599-6), dual to the Banach involutive algebra $C(X)$, and we can restore $X$ from $M(X)=C(X)^*$ (since $C(X)$ can be restored from $M(X)$ as the [stereotype dual space](https://handwiki.org/wiki/Stereotype_space)).
- But if we endow $M(X)=C(X)^*$ with the usual Banach dual topology to the topology of the predual Banach space $C(X)$ (with the variation of measure as norm), then it becomes not clear how to restore $X$ from $M(X)$, at least I don't know how to do this.

My question is the following:

> Are there some tricks that allow to reconstruct the topological space $X$ from the Banach space $M(X)$ of Radon measures on $X$? I suppose this could be done by endowing $M(X)$ with some supplementary structures like involution and the structure of coalgebra with respect to some tensor product, but my impression is that this is not enough: there must be a new supplementary structure on $M(X)$ that allows to reconstruct the topology of $X$. What is this structure, does anybody know?

I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: The extreme points of the unit ball gives some information

Comment: Let $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ be a Borel measurable isomorphism that is not continuous. Then $f$ induces a different compact topology on $[0,1]$ with the same Borel $\sigma$-algebra. This implies that the spaces of Radon measures on them with the variation norm coincide even though the spaces do not. So one cannot recover the topology. But $X$ can be homeomorphically be identified with the space of Dirac measures on $X$ when using the weak*-topology.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker what is meant by the weak*-topology, if we cannot restore $C(X)$? I think that there must be some supplementary structure, which is not well-known and which must be postulated on $M(X)$ and this will allow to reconstruct $C(X)$ and the topology on $X$.

Comment: @bathalf15320 how will you define topology on the extreme points?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov All I am saying is you can recover the topology on $X$ from the weak*-topology on $M(X)$. But you cannot recover it from the norm topology on $M(X)$.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker this is equivalent: if we can recover the $C(X)$-weak topology on $M(X)$, then we can recover $C(X)$ and $X$, and vice versa. And actually, the question is not how to recover all this if we know only the norm topology on $M(X)$: we can also define supplementary structures on $M(X)$, like inviolution, the structure of coalgebra and something what I don't know. Is it possible that establishing some (algebraic) structures on $M(X)$ gives everything?

Comment: So by "reconstruct" you mean the following: if the Banach spaces $M(X)$, $M(Y)$ are isometrically isomorphic, is then $X\cong Y$ (homeomorphic)? Or if this is not the intended meaning, can you please clarify.

Comment: The first answer here shows that $X$ can not be reconstructed in this sense: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1380/isomorphisms-of-banach-spaces

Comment: @ChristianRemling Christian, actually I thought that there must be a construction like the construction of spectrum of algebra, that allows to recover $X$ from $M(X)$+some supplementary structures on $M(X)$. If we know only the properties of $M(X)$ as a Banach space, then, as Michael noted, we can't restore the topological space $X$. But if we endow $M(X)$ with some supplementary structures, like involution and the structure of coalgebra (in a resonable sense), then our chances increase.

Comment: However, I don't believe that these two structures, involution and the structure of coalgebra, are sufficient, I thought there must be some supplementary structure which I don't know. Of course, this is vague, but I asked this question just in case if I don't know something important.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker as far as I can see the topology induced by $f$ in your example makes $[0,1]$ homeomorphic to $[0,1]$ again; I'd take a Borel isomorphism between $[0,1]$ and $[0,1]^2$.

Comment: @KPHart The assumption that $f$ is not continuous guarantees that the transported topology is different. The point is exactly that there are two different compact Hausdorff topologies on the *same* set that give rise to the same Borel sets and, consequently, the same variation norm on the corresponding signed measures.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker True, but having the topologies homeomorphic makes it less exciting for me.

Comment: Given coalgebra structure, the collection of group-like element might give you the collection of Dirac deltas, which are homeomorphic to the base space (if you are assuming that you are using weak*-topology).

Comment: @AllenCho the question is how to restore $X$ when $M(X)$ is considered with the Banach topology.