# Is it possible to reconstruct the universally measurable sets in X from the $C^*$-algebra $C(X)^{**}$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, measure-theory

This continues my [question of two months ago](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/420205/is-it-possible-to-reconstruct-the-compact-space-x-from-the-space-of-measures). Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff topological space. We consider the $C^*$-algebra $C(X)$ of continuous functions on $X$, its dual space $C(X)^{*}=M(X)$ of measures, and the second dual space $C(X)^{**}=M(X)^*$ (each star $*$ means the Banach dual space, moreover, I endow $C(X)^{**}$ with the structure of  $C^*$-algebra, generated from $C(X)$, see the [book by G. Dales, F.K. Dashiell, Jr., A.T.-M. Lau, D. Strauss](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-32349-7), but they use the notation $C_0(X)''$).

People explained me in comments [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/420205/is-it-possible-to-reconstruct-the-compact-space-x-from-the-space-of-measures), that it is apparently impossible to restore the topology of $X$ from the structure of  $C(X)^{*}$ or of $C(X)^{**}$. I have a hope that at least the $\sigma$-algebra of [universally measurable sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_measurable_set) on $X$ (I mean, the sets $M\subseteq X$ which are measurable with respect to each measure $\mu\in C(X)^{*}$) can be restored from $C(X)^{*}$ or from $C(X)^{**}$. Is that true?

In particular, is it possible that the following proposition is true?

> If $X$ and $Y$ are two compact Hausdorff topological spaces such that their spaces $C(X)^{**}$ and $C(Y)^{**}$ are isomorphic as $C^*$-algebras,
> $$
> C(X)^{**}\cong C(Y)^{**},
> $$
> then there exists a bijection $\varphi:X\to Y$ such that for each set $M\subseteq X$, $M$ is universally measurable in $X$ if and only if its image $\varphi(M)\subseteq Y$ is universally measurable in $Y$.

The existence of some (bijective) mapping $\varphi:X\to Y$ follows from the fact that elements of $X$ can be restored from $C(X)^{**}$ as isolated points of its spectrum ([H. G. Dales, A. T.-M. Lau, D. Strauss, Second duals of measure algebras, Corollary 4.2](https://eprints.lancs.ac.uk/id/eprint/55803/1/DissertatmeasurealgebraSUBMITTEDCHANGES.pdf)). But why does this mapping preserve universally measurable sets?

P.S. I asked this also at [MathStackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4480047/is-it-possible-to-reconstruct-the-universally-measurable-sets-in-x-from-the-c).